# What does "half-primitive vigor" mean?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, clark-ashton-smith

In the short story [The Planet of the Dead](http://www.eldritchdark.com/writings/short-stories/167/the-planet-of-the-dead) by Clark Ashton Smith, I would like to understand the meaning of "half-primitive vigor":

> He had lived as an intellectual sybarite; and by virtue of a
> half-primitive vigor, had not yet fallen upon the spiritual exhaustion
> and desolation, the dread implacable ennui of racial senescence, that
> marked so many of his fellows.

There are several meanings in the dictionary but none make really sense to me with "half".

Answer (score 2):

I'm suprsed that the question was migrated. The use of "half + adjective" is common enough:

"He was half-dead with exhaustion".

"She was half-aware of a conversation taking place in the adjoining room".

"I was half-convinced by the ridiculous argument."

etc.

The meaning of "half" is not literal but more "partly" or "to a lesser degree" or "almost" - the context will decide.

Thus  "and by virtue of a half-primitive vigor" =  and by virtue of **his** vigor which comprised a mixture of basic survival instincts common to all people and creatures, as well as more sophisticated techniques learned from his experience, etc.

Comment: The question was originally closed on ELU, so I flagged it for migration in order to save it.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison here turns on "half-primitive vigor" vs. "racial senescence."  A people early in their history (by which is generally meant their appearance in historical records -- a concept more applicable to *civilizations*, though not strong even there, but unfortunately commonly applied to races in 1932) are bursting with life and can-do vigor.  As their history accumulates, the people *as a whole* age through a maturity and end up in senescence -- decadence being a more direct and less metaphorical term.

Now, the character referred to does not actually have "primitive vigor" -- he does not come from a young, vigorous, energic race.  However, through some fluke, he has inherited a half-measure of it (half not being precise here) from his ancestors, and this prevents his sybarite habits from turning him into a case of spiritual exhaustion and desolation,